# Show head only for first page in jspdf-autotable 3.1.1

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using [jspdf-autotable](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable) for generating pdf report. I want the header text will only be shown for the first page but not working when setting this option `showHead: 'firstPage'`
For example: Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bablukpik/vh0g789L/18/)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The showHead option is for the table header and will not affect the hooks. If you want to have the same behavior for the hooks you can check the data parameter `data.pageNumber` and conditionally draw your content base on it.

Comment: Can you give me an example of it, Sir? @Simon Bengtsson

Comment: I have two header and 2nd header carry forward some value from previous page. And I don't want to show 2nd header in first page.

Comment: didParseCell: (HookData) => {if (HookData.doc.getNumberOfPages() === 1 && HookData.section === 'head' && HookData.row.index === 1) { return false }}